# Fatal Python error: PyGILState_Release when writing to a TextCtrl from a RadioBox handler

Tags: python, wxpython

I have a dialog box with a TextCtrl which has its value modified in a RadioBox handler. When running the code, the first click on the radio button is okay, but clicking a second time I get a  "Fatal Python error: PyGILState_Release: thread state 0x7facc7d078d0 must be current when releasing"

If the WriteText are commented out, the problem does not occur.

```
import wx


class MySplitDialog(wx.Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent, iid, title):
        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, parent, iid, title)

        base_vsizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        base_hsizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.label1 = wx.StaticText(self, label="Change this:")
        base_hsizer.Add(self.label1, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER | wx.ALL, 5)
        self.data_weight = wx.TextCtrl(self, value="1000", size=[80, -1],
                                       style=wx.TE_READONLY | wx.TE_RIGHT)
        base_hsizer.Add(self.data_weight, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER | wx.ALL, 5)
        base_vsizer.Add(base_hsizer, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER | wx.ALL, 5)

        # Add a Radio Box
        self.radio_ctl = wx.RadioBox(self, label="Split on basis of",
                                     choices=["A", "B", "C"],
                                     majorDimension=1, style=wx.RA_SPECIFY_COLS)
        self.radio_ctl.SetSelection(1)
        base_vsizer.Add(self.radio_ctl, 0, wx.GROW | wx.ALL, 5)
        self.radio_ctl.Bind(wx.EVT_RADIOBOX, self.on_radio_box)
        self.SetSizer(base_vsizer)

    def on_radio_box(self, event):
        self.data_weight.Clear()
        if event.Int == 0:
            self.data_weight.WriteText("A")
        elif event.Int == 1:
            self.data_weight.WriteText("B")
        else:
            self.data_weight.WriteText("C")


app = wx.App(False)
MySplitDialog(None, 0, "Split").ShowModal()
app.MainLoop()
```

I would expect that I could click as many times on a radio button without the fatal error to occur.

- Python versions: 2.7, 3.7, 3.9
- WxPython: 4.1.1, 4.2.0

The problem occurs on MacOS 11.7.4, but not on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Does anything change if you modify your handler like this:

```
def on_radio_box(self, event):
    self.data_weight.Clear()
    if event.Int == 0:
        text = 'A'
    elif event.Int == 1:
        text = 'B'
    else:
        text = 'C'

    wx.CallAfter(self.data_weight.WriteText, text)
```

?

Comment: Nope, still the same result:


Fatal Python error: PyGILState_Release: thread state 0x7fbc427057c0 must be current when releasing
Python runtime state: initialized

Comment: Does it happen even if you remove the .Clear() call at the top? If yes, then it must be a Mac-specific issue, and I have no clue where the problem may be.

Comment: Removing the clear at the top makes it okay. Also doing the WriteText in the handler is fine now. So it is related to the Clear() preceding the WriteText.

I guess you were not able to reproduce this? I'll give it a try on a newer MacOS (12.6.3) as well. And further more I'll test it on Windows. I report on this later.

Comment: I don’t have a Mac - and I’ve never seen this problem on Windows